# The class MyApplication can be designed, but is not the first class in the file

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm having some issues with my code. I'm trying to fix a WinForm that's giving me this error:

> The class MyApplication can be designed, but is not the first class in the file.  Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file.  Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file and try loading the designer again.

I removed all classes above the form in question, but it is still giving an error, and tried to rebuild the solution to no avail.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: With the code you provided, there isn't much help we can give you.

Comment: How much of the code should I post then?

Comment: Don't know, but chances are, you have more than one class in your file, and the designer doesn't like that.  More specifically, you probably have a class that comes *before* your form class in the same file.

Comment: There was a class before it (I assume), and I deleted it, so now the only class is the form class. Is there any other file where that deleted class would still be there?

Comment: Close any open files and rebuild your project.

Comment: Tried rebuilding it, still not working. Also tried restarting Visual Studio to no avail. If it helps, this happen after trying to add GeckoFx via NuGet

Comment: You are still talking about details we can't see.

Comment: If it is custom class of yours, change the name  VB already has an Application class

Comment: It's not a custom class. The class is called "MainForm". I don't think Visual Studio recognizes the form as a form anymore, and will not let me load the designer

Comment: Your message does not say MainForm, it says MyApplication.

Comment: I'm aware. That's what's confusing me, because I've never created a class called MyApplication.

Comment: I've fixed it.... the issue was that the MainForm.Designer file had the partial class of MyApplication, when the form is supposed to be MainForm. Super weird